# Devolver un arreglo de "Mascota" con programación funcional - Java

Tags: java, programación-funcional, lambda

Estoy tratando de aprender programación funcional y tengo un problema al devolver un array de objetos de la clase Mascota, la idea es filtrar por raza todos los que sean perros, lo que se hasta ahora es filtrar y devolver una List con Collectors pero lo que quiero es filtrar y devolver un array de Mascota[] pasando por parámetro el original

(La clase mascota solo tiene nombre, edad, raza y sus getters)

Tomando esto que hice para filtrar los números de un array

```
private int[] filtrados(int[] array, int menor) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).filter(p -> p < menor).toArray();
}
```

Quise intentar filtrar por raza las mascotas (mas que raza es que tipo de mascota)

Teniendo esto como resultado:

```
private Mascota[] filtrarPerros(Mascota[] mascotas) {
    return Arrays.stream(mascotas).filter(m -> m.getRaza().equals("perro")).toArray();
}
```

Lo que me pide que convierta el array de Mascota[] a Object[] o que haga un cast a Mascota[]

Lo que es raro porque la lista que estoy filtrando es de mascotas y debería devolver Mascota[] al igual que con el int, se que estoy haciendo algo mal, porque haciendo cualquiera de los casos no da con el resultado esperado.

Recorriendo con el forEach la lista una vez hecho el cast

```
Arrays.asList(filtrarPerros(mascotas)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Da este error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lmain.Mascota;
```

Convirtiendo de Mascota[] a Object[] al recorrer la lista de la manera anterior me da lo siguiente:

```
main.Mascota@18e8568
main.Mascota@33e5ccce
main.Mascota@5a42bbf4
```

Estos objetos son los tres perros que tengo en mi arreglo de Mascotas, entonces hice un cast mientras recorro la lista:

```
Arrays.asList(filtrarPerros(mascotas)).forEach(m -> {
        Mascota mascota = (Mascota) m;
        System.out.println(mascota.getNombre());
    });
```

Ahí si que devuelve los nombres reales de las mascotas filtradas, pero aun así debería haber una forma de hacer lo que quiero.

¿Como haría para que filtre y devuelva un arreglo de Mascota[]?

¿Porque no me ha devuelto en si el arreglo ya de las mascotas[] en vez de tener que hacer el casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era crear una matriz del tipo que quiero devolver en `toArray(T[])` y no `Object[] toArray()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-- y https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-

Al parecer toArray() devuelve un arreglo de objetos por lo que nosotros una vez obtenida la matriz tenemos que realizar el casting a el tipo deseado, como dice en la documentación: (traducido)

> La matriz devuelta será "segura" en el sentido de que esta colección no mantiene referencias a ella. (En otras palabras, este método debe asignar una nueva matriz incluso si esta colección está respaldada por una matriz). **Por tanto, la persona que llama es libre de modificar la matriz devuelta.**

Pero si utilizo `toArray(T[])` este me permite agregar el tipo de objeto al arreglo que deseo retornar.

> Devuelve una matriz que contiene todos los elementos de esta colección; el tipo de tiempo de ejecución de la matriz devuelta es el de la matriz especificada. Si la colección encaja en la matriz especificada, se devuelve allí. **De lo contrario, se asigna una nueva matriz con el tipo de tiempo de ejecución de la matriz especificada y el tamaño de esta colección.**

Dicho esto hay que asignar el tipo de objeto a devolver en `toArray(T[])`, en este caso no especifique el tamaño de la matriz a retornar, de igual forma retorna una matriz con los 3 objetos que había para filtrar, también lo explica en la documentación

```
.toArray(Mascota[]::new);
```